# Selenium : Table is not printing in correct format

Tags: python, selenium, selenium-webdriver

Please Help me! I have the following table in a webpage that want to scrape:
[image]

```
table=driver.find_element_by_xpath("/html/body/div[2]/div/main/div[2]/div[4]/div[3]/div/div[1]/div/div[1]/div[1]/div/div[2]/div/table")
    rows=table.find_elements_by_class_name("institutional-holdings__row")
    for row in rows:
        for x in range(0,2):
            col = row.find_elements(By.TAG_NAME, "td")[x]
            print(col.text)
```

then my output is :

```
Institutional Ownership
70.82 %
Total Shares Outstanding (millions)
7,532
Total Value of Holdings (millions)
$1,372,078
```

and output I want :

```
Institutional Ownership70.82 %
Total Shares Outstanding (millions)7,532
Total Value of Holdings (millions)$1,372,078
```

problem I'm having is that it's printing each column one by one. loop is iterating for all columns at one time. I want to print one row column at at one iteration.

Comment: had you checked if "\n" is presented on the string? maybe it cause the break line

Answer (score 0):

If you want to collect each row texts and the print them, not to print each column in each row immediately. Try something like this:

```
table=driver.find_element_by_xpath("/html/body/div[2]/div/main/div[2]/div[4]/div[3]/div/div[1]/div/div[1]/div[1]/div/div[2]/div/table")
    rows=table.find_elements_by_class_name("institutional-holdings__row")
    for row in rows:
        row_text = ""        
        for x in range(0,2):            
            col = row.find_elements(By.TAG_NAME, "td")[x]
            row_text = row_text + col.text
            row_text = row_text + " "
        print(row_text.strip())
```

I also added a space between cells texts in the row to make it more clear.

Comment: its ok append function on a string??

Comment: I'm appending text, not a function

Comment: AttributeError: 'str' object has no attribute 'append'

Comment: Ok, changed that. Thanks